# Angular 4 order of elements

Tags: angular

Is there a way to implement some sort of ordering on HTML elements with Angular 2? So for example:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" [order]="2">
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" [order]="3">
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" [order]="1">
        </a>
    </div>
```

So that I can ultimately connect those to `ngModel` and programatically assign order to elements?

Comment: Are the dropdown items static or pulled from a database?

Comment: No, unless you use `*ngFor` to generate your `<a></a>`

Comment: Elements should be static (though this is maybe a bad example because I want to reorder table columns on click)